# Encrypt images before node saving and decrypt them when a node is viewed

Tags: files

I am searching for a way to encrypt images before saving them on server (private folder) and decrypt it when node is rendered for roles that have views permissions.

I found the [Encrypted Files](https://www.drupal.org/project/encrypted_files) module, but it's not covered by Drupal’s security advisory policy.

I installed and configured both the available versions (1.x , 2.x). It seems files are encrypted successfully, but I can see the image when I view a node or in the image preview widget because it seems it can't be decrypted.

How can I use this module? Is there any video guidance? I searched Internet but I didn't find any useful video.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I don't see the need to encrypt images as Private files will hide the images from direct access and will be served by Drupal.

You can find more about private files [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/skilling/installation/set-up-a-private-file-path)

Encryption and decryption each time the node is viewed can have serious performance implications.

The only scenario that I would think of having encryption when there is a security concern of direct access to the server and then I will, for sure, not use PHP to do that for me as most Linux systems are providing [encryption natively](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiNrNv-tcbiAhWRlhQKHfAFA8cQFjACegQIDxAH&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.linux.com%2Flearn%2Fhow-encrypt-linux-file-system-dm-crypt&usg=AOvVaw3wy3ncE_aOUnG0aXxRyxU-).

Can you share with us your requirements and scenario?